# Sealed case object vs Enumeratum and issue of serialization in scala

Tags: scala, enums

I am learning about Enumerations and its supposed benefit, which are not obvious to me at this point. Indeed the first thing I thought of when I saw it used was, why not using Algebraic DataType instead.

Then found this blog: https://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/

With the following example:

```
sealed trait Weekday

case object Monday extends Weekday
case object Tuesday extends Weekday
case object Wednesday extends Weekday
case object Thursday extends Weekday
case object Friday extends Weekday
case object Saturday extends Weekday
case object Sunday extends Weekday
```

But then

> Problems with sealed case objects  ...
>
> - there is no simple way to retrieve all the enumeration values
> - there are no default serialize/deserialize methods
> - there is no default ordering between enumeration values - this can be achieved manually by
>   including some info on the values ...

While i understand point 1 and 3 and indeed i barely have this needs, i don't understand point 2

> there are no default serialize/deserialize methods

My understanding is that case object are serializable. Hence I do not get it?

Can someone explain?

*Also I really don't see the advantage over using algebraic datatype.*

Comment: It's serializable. It just doesn't have a generated method to do serialization. You can manually create the methods using java io stream though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > there are no default serialize/deserialize methods

> My understanding is that case object are serializable. Hence I do not get it ?

If you read the other examples you can see the author means methods to convert to/from `String`. Of course, `toString` gives you one direction:

```
Monday.toString == "Monday"
```

But there's no method get the value from its name unless you write your own:

```
Weekday.???("Monday") == Monday
```

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the article, it is elaborating about the native Scala enumeration. One of the advantages shown there of the native Scala enumeration, is the serialization/deserialization, followed by the example:

> ```
> scala> Weekday.Monday.toString
> res0: String = Monday
>
> scala> Weekday.withName("Monday")
> res1: Weekday.Value = Monday
> ```

When using case objects, let's assume we have:

```
sealed trait Weekday

case object Monday extends Weekday
```

Then you can serialize easily:

```
scala> Monday.toString
res0: String = Monday
```

But having the string `Monday`, it is not easy to get back the case object `Monday`.